# Does Apache JMeter support http/2 requests？

Tags: jmeter, apache-httpclient-4.x

Does JMeter 3.2 support HTTP2 ?

Comment: From my knowledge, I don't think the support of HTTP/2 is available in JMeter yet. Change log for 3.1 is here http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From HTTPClient 4.5 [official docs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html):

> Standards based, pure Java, implementation of HTTP versions 1.0 and
>   1.1

SO, you need to wait till HTTP/2 is implemented in `HTTPClient` libraries and Jmeter implements HTTP2 using the library and create a sampler for the same.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

HTTP2 is not supported by Core JMeter as of version 4.0

But there is a [plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/http2/README.md) that implements it.

This [plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=http2) can be installed by [JMeter-Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/).

Regarding HTTP Client, since version 5.0 released on 18 January 2018, Http/2 is supported:

- https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/index.html
- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-httpclient-users/201801.mbox/%3C1516280327.10018.3.camel%40apache.org%3E

Answer (score 2):

To sample HTTP/2 requests, you can use a plugin for jmeter, such as this one: https://github.com/syucream/jmeter-http2-plugin

From the readme file:

- Build Netty 5 (Alpha3+) and netty-tcnative for your platform
- Copy HTTP2Sampler.jar, netty-all.jar, netty-tcnative.jar and
  hpack.jar to lib/ext of jmeter directory
- If you use gzip encoding, you must prepare jzlib.jar too.
- Run JMeter
- Write your test scenario with HTTP2Sampler

Comment: This plugin has not been updated since 2015, but there are active forks such as https://github.com/goecho/jmeter-http2-plugin - YMMV